# go get fails with private bitbucket repositories, getting server response: Access denied and 404 error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have used in Docker for go build with get private bitbucket repo but Always getting  403 forbidden and Access denied error, like below.

```
[91mgo: missing Mercurial command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
[0m[91mgo: missing Mercurial command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
[0m[91mgo get bitbucket.org/Mycompany/app-client: reading https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/Mycompany/app-client?fields=scm: 403 Forbidden
    server response: Access denied. You must have write or admin access.
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c go get bitbucket.org/Mycompany/app-client' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have added in docker file like below , also added jenkins user id_rsa.pub in bitbucket.

```
ARG ssh_prv_key
ARG ssh_pub_key
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN  echo "    IdentityFile /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa " >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

RUN git config --global user.email "admin@Mycompany
RUN git config --global user.name admin
RUN  echo "    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

then :- `docker build -t example --build-arg ssh_prv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" --build-arg ssh_pub_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" --squash .`

For ubuntu VM its getting correctly , but from Docker only getting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you `ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa`, ensure you're using the `root` user for the next steps (needing SSH).

Also, ensure the Bitbucket Repository doesn't have IP filtering enabled or it allows the right IPs.

Comment: `Step 21/25 : RUN whoami
 ---> Running in 54abad5dfd74
root`
I have chked different stage getting USER, it is root only, and there have no IP filtering in Bitbucket. but getting same error